# MapReduce Nutch tutorials

Tags: java, mapreduce, nutch

Could some one give me pointers to tutorials that explains how to write a mapreduce program into Nutch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521981) is a good resource on MapReduce in general. Chapter 14 contains several case studies of Hadoop and one of them is about Nutch. It helps me see the way Nutch uses Hadoop and MapReduce.